# Dose any can give me a little theoretical support about nav_msgs/Odometry

Tags: ros, odometry, ros-noetic

guys. I have a question about nav_msgs/Odometry.

I have read the repo https://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom about how to publish odometry over ROS. But in this code, did not tell how to publish covariance.

So, my question, How to confirm covariance when use nav_msgs/Odometry, and if we get this data, and how to use it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I will take as an example the code in the [link](https://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) you mentioned to answer your question, and I hope you do not mind if I take the opportunity to explain some additional details.

Let us take for example the following lines:

```
  62     //set the position
  63     odom.pose.pose.position.x = x;
  64     odom.pose.pose.position.y = y;
  65     odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
```

`odom` is a an object of type `nav_msgs::msg::Odometry` generated from the message definition of the message `Odometry.msg` in the package `nav_msgs`.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html), Odometry has 4 attributes:

- an `header` of type `std_msgs::Header`
- a `child_frame_id` of type `string`
- a `pose` of type `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance`
- a `twist` of type `geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovariance`

Since `odom` is a C++ object, we can access its attributes with the `.` operator; then `odom.pose` is again an object, this time of type `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance`. Reading the [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovariance.html) we can see that it has two attributes:

- a `pose` of type `geometry_msgs/Pose`
- a `covariance` of type `float[36]`

`odom.pose.pose` then access the `pose` attribute of the `pose` of `odom`. And so on and so forth for `position`, `x`, `y`, and `z`.
So, you just need to write `odom.pose.covariance` to get access to the array of floating point numbers storing the covariance of the position and linear velocity data.

To access the covariance of the orientation and angular velocity data, you just need to write `odom.twist.covariance`.

Notice that according to the [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovariance.html), the covariance matrix is stored *row wise*, which means that:

- `odom.pose.covariance[0]`, ..., `odom.pose.covariance[0]` is the first row of the matrix
- `odom.pose.covariance[6]`, ..., `odom.pose.covariance[11]` is the second row of the matrix

and so on.